# How to prevent concurrent function invocations?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

I'm having a problem:

I have a PostgreSQL function that performs a `FOR` loop over `table_a` records and inserts into `table_b` using data from both tables, and all records are linked by the same *process number*.

Example:

```
DECLARE
......

BEGIN

FOR rec in 

(select * from table_a where *some_condition*)

LOOP

some_value := (select value from table_b where some_condition_2);

insert into table_b (some_field, process) VALUES (some_value + rec.other_value, some_process);


END LOOP

COMMIT;

END;
```

if I call that function simultaneously in two sessoins, the expected result in `table_a` should be:

```
(process 1) record 1
(process 1) record 2
(process 1) record 3
(process 1) record 4
(process 1) record 5
(process 2) record 6
(process 2) record 7
(process 2) record 8
(process 2) record 9
(process 2) record 10
```

because I guess when I call the function, all *inserts* should be executed in a row without interruption.

But sometimes they get executed in this way:

```
(process 1) record 1
(process 1) record 2
(process 1) record 3
(process 2) record 4 (*)
(process 1) record 5
(process 2) record 6 (*)
(process 1) record 7
(process 2) record 8
(process 2) record 9
(process 2) record 10
```

and the value of `some_field` in `table_a` is wrong.

why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that keeps the function from running concurrently in multiple sessions and concurrently selecting and inserting data.

To make sure that no two invocations of the function can run at the same time, you best use an [advisory lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ... AS
$$BEGIN
   PERFORM pg_advisory_lock(42);

   /* processing */

   PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock(42);
END;$$;
```

The key 42 is a number of your choosing.